# Mongoid and changing structure of database

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

The specific change that I'd like to make is that I'd like to get rid of a base class of model. Say I have a base class Fruit and then I have two different extending fruits classes Orange and Banana.

So I have something like this:

```
class Fruit
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :weight, type: Integer
end
class Orange < Fruit
end
class Banana < Fruit
end
```

And I'd like to convert that to this without loosing any data or references to fruits:

```
class Orange
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :weight, type: Integer
end
class Banana
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :weight, type: Integer
end
```

P.S. Please don't question my reasons for why I want to seemingly break the rule of DRY and get rid of the inheritance. I have my reasons and they are good :) and the ultimate idea is to refactor the duplicate stuff into a module.

Comment: I'd guess that you'd have to split the `fruits` collection into two pieces (`oranges` and `bananas`) by hand before this would work. There should be a `type` field in `fruits` for the SCI, that and a little bit of JavaScript should let you fix the data right inside MongoDB.

Comment: Could you elaborate that a bit further? What would be the steps to take to complete this on the database and Rails sides? Would it perhaps be beneficial to use something like:
https://github.com/nviennot/mongoid_lazy_migration or
https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations or how should I run the migration with the required JavaScript commands?